# Complicated Lookup in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a table1 in Excel on sheet1 showing options of products separated by commas.

| Model | Options |
| --- | --- |
| G35UA | A30E,F41A,F01B |
| G35UD | A30E,F41A,F01B,PDIA |
| G35US | A30E,F41A,K36B |
| G35UF | A30E,XA43,L37A,J18G |
| G35UB | A30E,F41A,F01B,FOOD,XA43,S10A |

And I have a table2 on sheet2 showing the definition of options.

| Option | Definition |
| --- | --- |
| A30E | Backup Camera |
| F41A | Fire Ext |
| F01B | Drive Tires |
| PDIA | Factory PDI |
| K21D | Backup Alarm |
| E911 | Cascade SS |
| K36B | K Pad |
| D59B | Full Dashboard |
| TR96 | Tail |
| S10A | Sun Roof |

I would like to see the third column on sheet1 that lookups the Definitions based on the Options.

| Model | Options | Definition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| G35UA | A30E,F41A,F01B | Backup Camera, Fire Ext, Drive Tires |
| G35UD | A30E,F41A,F01B,PDIA | Backup Camera, Fire Ext, Drive Tires, Factory PDI |
| G35US | A30E,F41A,K36B | Backup Camera, Fire Ext, K Pad |
| G35UF | A30E,XA43,L37A,J18G | Backup Camera |
| G35UB | A30E,F41A,F01B,FOOD,XA43,S10A | Backup Camera, Fire Ext, Drive Tires, Sun Roof |

I wasn't successful with the vlookup function because the Options separated by commas and also the Find, the search and the Index and match functions didn't help because the number of options is varied.
I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your options are always four characters long and therefor you don't need to worry about them being a substring in another option. That way you don't need to pad them with commas for exact matching. So using Microsoft365, try:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(B$9:B$18,ISNUMBER(FIND(A$9:A$18,B2))))
```

In Excel 2019, youd use a CSE-entered formula, for example:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(A$9:A$18,B2)),B$9:B$18,""))
```

In any other case I'd advise you to start developing an UDF to mimic the `TEXTJOIN()` functionality.

Comment: Thanks very much, @JvdV you are awesome. I'm using Excel 2016 and TEXTJOIN is not a known function on that and also I have no experience with the UDF. Any idea for that.